# How to cut one row to starttime and endtime to mutiple day spend hour rows

Tags: sql, oracle

#### Question:

How to cut one row to starttime and endtime to mutiple day spend hour rows

#### Table Data and DDL:

```
starttime           , endtime
2019/05/03 08:00:00 , 2019/05/05 12:00:00
```

```
CREATE TABLE T  ("starttime" timestamp, "endtime" timestamp);
INSERT  INTO T ("starttime", "endtime") VALUES ('03-May-2019 08:00:00 AM', '05-May-2019 12:00:00 PM');
```

#### Expected Result:

```
Date        , SpendHour
2019/05/03 , 16
2019/05/04 , 24
2019/05/05 , 12
```

[Online Demo Link | DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd908e2fd2be0d6118c40da61ad2d469)

Comment: is there an id column in your table which can identify unique startdate & endate combinations?

Comment: yes every row has one pk id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `connect by level <=` syntax combined with `case..when` statements

```
select trunc(t.starttime+level-1) as "Date", 
       case 
       when trunc(t.starttime+level-1) = trunc(t.starttime) then
            extract(hour from trunc(t.starttime+level)
                  -greatest(t.starttime,trunc(t.starttime+level-1)))     
       when trunc(t.starttime+level-1) = trunc(t.endtime) then     
            extract(hour from t.endtime-trunc(t.endtime))
       else
            24     
       end as "Spend hour"   
  from t
 connect by level <= extract(day from t.endtime - t.starttime)+1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/SHO31569)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

even though there surely will be more elegant solutions. This will bring the desired result:

```sql
WITH cte ( starttime ) AS (
     SELECT
         CAST(TO_DATE('03.05.2019:08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy:hh24:mi:ss') AS DATE) cte_date
     FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST( (starttime + 1) AS DATE) starttime
     FROM cte
     WHERE trunc(starttime) + 1 <= TO_DATE('05.05.2019:12:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy:hh24:mi:ss')
 ),starttime AS (
     SELECT
         TO_DATE('03.05.2019:08:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy:hh24:mi:ss') AS starttime
     FROM dual
 ),endtime AS (
     SELECT
         TO_DATE('05.05.2019:12:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy:hh24:mi:ss') AS endtime
     FROM dual
 )
 SELECT
     a.*,
     CASE 
        WHEN TO_CHAR( (trunc(times + 1) ),'hh24') - TO_CHAR(times,'hh24') = 0 THEN -24 *-1
        ELSE ( 24 - ( TO_CHAR( (trunc(times + 1) ),'hh24') - TO_CHAR(times,'hh24') ) *-1 )
     END diff
 FROM(
     SELECT
         CASE 
            WHEN TO_CHAR(starttime,'yyyy-mm-dd') = (SELECT TO_CHAR(endtime,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM endtime) THEN 
                (  SELECT endtime FROM endtime )
            WHEN TO_CHAR(starttime,'yyyy-mm-dd') = (SELECT TO_CHAR(starttime,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM starttime) THEN 
                (  SELECT starttime FROM starttime )
            ELSE trunc(starttime)
         END times
     FROM cte a
 ) a
```

Result:

```
 TIMES                 DIFF
 03/05/2019 08:00:00   16
 04/05/2019            24
 05/05/2019 12:00:00   12
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this bro,
you can change the final select into "SELECT * FROM tbl" to see how it run.

```
;WITH tbl AS 
(
    SELECT "starttime" AS Date0,
        DATEADD(HH,24-DATEPART(HH,"starttime"),"starttime") AS "endtime0",
        DATEDIFF(HH,"starttime",DATEADD(HH,24-DATEPART(HH,"starttime"),"starttime")) AS SPENTTIME,
        "endtime"
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date0+1,"endtime0"+1,
    CASE WHEN "endtime0"+1>"endtime" THEN DATEDIFF(HH,Date0+1,DATEADD(HH,24-DATEPART(HH,"endtime"),Date0+1))
        ELSE 
        DATEDIFF(HH,Date0+1,DATEADD(HH,24,Date0+1)) END AS SPENTTIME ,
        "endtime"
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Date0+1<"endtime"
) 
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),Date0,111) AS Date,SPENTTIME
FROM tbl
```